# dynamically flatten json using snowflake function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to dynamically flatten json using snowflake function ?

select key,value from table a ,lateral flatten(input => variant_column)

gives

[image: key | value empname| e1 empid | 123 empname| e2 empid | 345]

which need to be converted as

[image]

Comment: Please provide the source JSON as text. It will help vs. trying to reverse engineer it from the flattened data in the table picture.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed your source JSON is something like this:

```json
[
    {
        "empname": "e1",
        "empid": 123
    },
    {
        "empname": "e2",
        "empid": 456
    }
]
```

Based on this, you can achieve the output you want using:

```sql
select
    s.value:empname::varchar as empname,
    s.value:empid::number as empid
from
    json j,
    lateral flatten (input => j.src, path => '', mode => 'ARRAY') s
;
```

---

Full example replication code:

```sql
create or replace table json (src variant);

insert into json(src) select parse_json($$
[
    {
        "empname": "e1",
        "empid": 123
    },
    {
        "empname": "e2",
        "empid": 456
    }
]
$$
);

select * from json;

select
    s.value:empname::varchar as empname,
    s.value:empid::number as empid
from
    json j,
    lateral flatten (input => j.src, path => '', mode => 'ARRAY') s
;
```

Comment: thanks for your input ,I am looking for a solution where json keys are not known in advance ,so it need to be done dynamically

Comment: Please update your question to reflect this. That this is your specific requirement isn’t clear from your question.